# aws ecs cli not outputting the capacity provided name

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs, aws-cli

Hi I am trying to run the following command and I expected the cli to return the capacity provider name (FARGATE, FARGARE_SPOT) of the ECS task as described in the doc [1](https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/latest/reference/ecs/describe-tasks.html#output). But the command does not return that in attribute in the output. Here is the command and aws cli version i am running.

```
% aws --version
aws-cli/2.2.46 Python/3.8.8 Darwin/20.6.0 exe/x86_64 prompt/off

% aws ecs describe-tasks --cluster ab-demo-cluster \
                       --tasks \
                         $(aws ecs list-tasks --cluster ab-demo-cluster --query 'taskArns[]' --output text) \
                       --query 'sort_by(tasks,&availabilityZone)[].{
                                          Id: taskArn,
                                          AZ: availabilityZone,
                                          CP: capacityProviderName
                                         }' \
                        --output table
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|                                                   DescribeTasks                                                  |
+------------+-------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|     AZ     |  CP   |                                             Id                                              |
+------------+-------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|  us-east-2a|  None |  arn:aws:ecs:us-east-2:184038358631:task/ab-demo-cluster/3979894a8aae4bb491e61f47af45fbfd   |
|  us-east-2a|  None |  arn:aws:ecs:us-east-2:184038358631:task/ab-demo-cluster/3efdfeb782c5430cb761ec17f9013370   |
|  us-east-2a|  None |  arn:aws:ecs:us-east-2:184038358631:task/ab-demo-cluster/56a59b10fd1a456299a3bcbfe4074fde   |
|  us-east-2b|  None |  arn:aws:ecs:us-east-2:184038358631:task/ab-demo-cluster/16f96ea3c02845a0bffec4165e358f39   |
|  us-east-2b|  None |  arn:aws:ecs:us-east-2:184038358631:task/ab-demo-cluster/7f8a5d2f585241a1886a6d4b8cc5ce9d   |
|  us-east-2b|  None |  arn:aws:ecs:us-east-2:184038358631:task/ab-demo-cluster/ad543623d9a64a6b9c57cac630487471   |
|  us-east-2c|  None |  arn:aws:ecs:us-east-2:184038358631:task/ab-demo-cluster/6156807b36af424388d8c915c4068f92   |
|  us-east-2c|  None |  arn:aws:ecs:us-east-2:184038358631:task/ab-demo-cluster/6a1f1e9897804521898831d3fbf28330   |
|  us-east-2c|  None |  arn:aws:ecs:us-east-2:184038358631:task/ab-demo-cluster/de9bea587f2349079cbb08d6864deb26   |
|  us-east-2c|  None |  arn:aws:ecs:us-east-2:184038358631:task/ab-demo-cluster/fdb128a008df4bccbb181b62ca43443c   |
+------------+-------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Here is the output without the query filter:

```
% aws ecs describe-tasks --cluster ab-demo-cluster --tasks arn:aws:ecs:us-east-2::task/ab-demo-cluster/16f96ea3c02845a0bffec4165e358f39
{
    "tasks": [
        {
            "attachments": [
                {
                    "id": "84bf2eea-94e2-46c0-abdc-ce4d25c556a0",
                    "type": "ElasticNetworkInterface",
                    "status": "ATTACHED",
                    "details": [
                        {
                            "name": "subnetId",
                            "value": "subnet-e156689b"
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "networkInterfaceId",
                            "value": "eni-04e50da277b89966f"
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "macAddress",
                            "value": "06:2e:f6:9e:5f:f2"
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "privateDnsName",
                            "value": "ip-172-31-25-52.us-east-2.compute.internal"
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "privateIPv4Address",
                            "value": "172.31.25.52"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ],
            "availabilityZone": "us-east-2b",
            "clusterArn": "arn:aws:ecs:us-east-2::cluster/ab-demo-cluster",
            "connectivity": "CONNECTED",
            "connectivityAt": "2021-10-22T11:40:33.959000+05:30",
            "containers": [
                {
                    "containerArn": "arn:aws:ecs:us-east-2::container/ab-demo-cluster/16f96ea3c02845a0bffec4165e358f39/14fd70d7-9825-4425-b2ff-08ff181b7507",
                    "taskArn": "arn:aws:ecs:us-east-2::task/ab-demo-cluster/16f96ea3c02845a0bffec4165e358f39",
                    "name": "node-backend-container",
                    "image": ".dkr.ecr.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/chetdhar-ab-demo:ab-demo-node-backend-v2",
                    "imageDigest": "sha256:7082d05c560da77dacbb1172846418213a396e7493db472f809f955cab4f6791",
                    "runtimeId": "16f96ea3c02845a0bffec4165e358f39-39335898",
                    "lastStatus": "RUNNING",
                    "networkBindings": [],
                    "networkInterfaces": [
                        {
                            "attachmentId": "84bf2eea-94e2-46c0-abdc-ce4d25c556a0",
                            "privateIpv4Address": "172.31.25.52"
                        }
                    ],
                    "healthStatus": "UNKNOWN",
                    "cpu": "1024",
                    "memoryReservation": "1024"
                }
            ],
            "cpu": "1024",
            "createdAt": "2021-10-22T11:40:29.880000+05:30",
            "desiredStatus": "RUNNING",
            "enableExecuteCommand": false,
            "group": "service:ab-demo-node-backend-service",
            "healthStatus": "UNKNOWN",
            "lastStatus": "RUNNING",
            "launchType": "FARGATE",
            "memory": "2048",
            "overrides": {
                "containerOverrides": [
                    {
                        "name": "node-backend-container"
                    }
                ],
                "inferenceAcceleratorOverrides": []
            },
            "platformVersion": "1.4.0",
            "pullStartedAt": "2021-10-22T11:40:48.161000+05:30",
            "pullStoppedAt": "2021-10-22T11:40:53.639000+05:30",
            "startedAt": "2021-10-22T11:40:58.240000+05:30",
            "startedBy": "ecs-svc/9740107988662602039",
            "tags": [],
            "taskArn": "arn:aws:ecs:us-east-2::task/ab-demo-cluster/16f96ea3c02845a0bffec4165e358f39",
            "taskDefinitionArn": "arn:aws:ecs:us-east-2:184038358631:task-definition/ab-demo-node-backend-taskdefination:1
2",
            "version": 3,
            "ephemeralStorage": {
                "sizeInGiB": 20
            }
        }
    ],
    "failures": []
}
```

Comment: I have tried the above command without the query filter as well. And the attribute is not even present in the output. Any thoughts?

Comment: What is the output without the query filter? Keeping the code as minimal as possible to reproduce the problem is best.

Comment: Updated the question without the query filter output. It seems like a bug to me in the aws cli

Comment: Does the API endpoint return it? Docs can be wrong sometimes...